# What is an example of coproducts being much different from products?

Tags: category-theory

From the wikipedia articles on coproducts and products:

"Essentially, the product of a family of objects is the "most general" object which admits a morphism to each of the given objects."

"The coproduct of a family of objects is essentially the "least specific" object to which each object in the family admits a morphism. (...) coproducts can be and typically are dramatically different from products."

I can see that in the coproduct explanation, each object does not need to have a morphism *to* some object, whereas the product does need that.

I am just trying to find an example that makes this difference (or any "dramatic difference") clearer. I guess the overall question would be, why does the dual notion provide such a different and a lot of times richer structure if "all we are doing" is reversing the source and target of morphisms and their order of composition?

Comment: Have you seen _any_ examples of products and coproducts?  They are very different in almost all natural examples (with a few important exceptions).

Comment: Yes, specifically the one on the category of sets. I guess I have an inadequate question. My problem is why does the dual notion of a category contain such a different structure, and a lot of the times richer (according to some articles I've read)?

Comment: @TheBosco It's hard to know what would be a satisfying answer to that "why." What would you say if someone asked, *why* are rings so different from manifolds? In any case, for any meaning of "richer", it's true at most half the time that the opposite category has "richer" structure than the original category, since every category is the opposite of its opposite.